# Connecting random points to form a grid like network

Tags: graph, computational-geometry

I would like to connect some random points (let say 100) into a grid-like graph (similar to a quad mesh) with no edge crossing. My current approach is using Delaunay triangulation to form a network first, and then try to remove some of the edges by some heuristic such as removing the hypotenuse.

Is there any better way to do this? If this is the way to go what other heuristics or algorithms can be used to generate such a graph?

Comment: Do you have the points, and want to connect them, or just make a 'random' grid, it being ok to make up the points too? If the latter one possibility would be to start with a regular grid and wiggle the points; I think that as long as an internal point stays within the convex hull of its 4 neighbours, you won't get crossing lines.

Comment: I have the points already so the later options is not available. I will check out the convex hull options later.

Comment: If your points are truly random, I am not sure that this is possible at all (unless with extremely contorted geometries). I would try by hand on a small sample case.

Comment: The point is not truly random. But assume true randomnees generalized the problem